# jquery "new function" equivalent

Tags: jquery

Is there a jquery equivalent to this:

```
document.getElementById(cbxFieldID).onclick = new Function("hideUnhideRows('" + cbxFieldID + "','" + txtFieldID + "')");
```

Basically, I want to configure a click event for an element and pass 2 parameters to the function at runtime.
The problem is that the same variable values are passed regardless of the object clicked. Here is what I am using:

```
$(cbxFieldID).change(function () { 
   var $cbxField = $("#" + cbxFieldID);
   var $txtField = $("#" + txtFieldID);
   hideUnhideRows($cbxField,$txtField);
});
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

The arguments passed to the callback functions are event objects, containing arbitrary information about the event or the target. You can access the target by `evt.target` like so:

```
$("#" + cbxFieldID).change(function (evt) { 
   alert(evt.target);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#cbxFieldID').click(function () { 
    var $cbxField = $("#" + cbxFieldID);
    var $txtField = $("#" + txtFieldID);
    hideUnhideRows($cbxField,$txtField);
 });
```

That should do the trick unless i have missed something. in jQuery click is a function that you can bind to any element. Here we are doing it to the ID: `$('#cbxFieldID')`

Comment: tried this originally.  The problem is that the values are not passed at runtime.  I am looping though a list and setting up a dynamic function to be performed at runtime.  Basically queuing the function call.  Each time this function is called, the exact same values are passed (the last one's processed).  
Pretty sure I'm not explaining this correctly.  Thanks much.